# Battle of Seattle

Tags: united-states, political-history, protests

The "[Battle of Seattle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1999_Seattle_WTO_protests)," a large civil protest that led to sporadic rioting in 1999, is commonly portrayed as influential in the sociology of Western activism, and in the contemporary history of social movements and the left in the First World.  The "Battle of Seattle" was a "Summit protest" a protest aimed at the intergovernmental and intercorporate  summit meetings that occasionally occur, usually in a "world city," such as Seattle, Milan, Melbourne, etc.

Why has this event achieved influence in the scholarly literature?

The "Battle of Seattle" is sometimes considered influential as it allowed diversely structured, motivated and politically motivated groups to construct a weak shared collective identity.  In contrast to the "Parties" of the past, the event seems to have been organised by a protest "network," with a far looser collective identity of programme and organisation than previous left parties or movements.  It is often suggested that "the internet" allowed organisations and participants in the protest to form a collective identity.  How did the internet assist in forming "collective subjectivity" for the Seattle protest?

In addition:

- As 1989 is commonly portrayed in the history of the left as the moment when the possibility of a collective left program for widespread and radical social change, organised through bolshevik influenced communist parties, collapsed.  Has the role of "The Battle of Seattle" and subsequent "Summit Protests" been overstated in terms of the coherence of a post-1989 shared revolutionary political identity?
- Did the political violence of September 11, 2001 destroy the political sentiment that developed around the "Summit Protests" in the first world?

Comment: Is it influential?  I had never even heard of it until this question.

Comment: Welcome to History - Stack Exchange. Can you please add some details to your question, or at least leink it, so the people who are not familiar with the subject have easy access to description? Also can you link or quote the source for claiming that this event was influential.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what "allowing protesters facilitating weak identity ties through the internet" means, but my English is not good enough.

Comment: (Note to self: follow-up question on "battles that rhyme" :)

Comment: @DarekWędrychowski - It means someone was writing their sociology thesis, and "using social media" didn't sound jargony enough.

Comment: If I understand correctly this question observes that social media (Twitter, Facebook, etc.) are now often cited as catalysts of political change e.g. during times of turmoil and it asks for evidence as to whether this trend could first have come to force at the protests against the [WTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wto) meeting in 1999. I've heard similar arguments e.g. in relation to Arab-spring events in Lybia and Syria, but not to the more minor events in Seattle. So I'd expect the question to be clear about "seen by whom".

Comment: I know a couple of colleagues and comrades who work in this field.  I've clarified the question based on my understanding of the actual scholarly work in the field, and the contemporary debates in the scholarship.  The question is now answerable from literature.

Comment: The revisions significantly improve this question.  I was tempted to reopen after editing the title to "Why is the Battle of Seattle considered influential?", but (a) I still don't know who considers it influential and (b) most of the rest of the answer seems embedded in the question.  There may be a good question buried in here, but I'm not sure we have it yet.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - Side with them or not, it was a watershed event for the far left - sort of like asking about how the 2009 Tea Party Protests were organized on the right side of the equation - and an important part of recent American history =and= Internet history, as it was where Indymedia came into its own. I had no trouble understanding what was being asked, and the question is now much improved.

Comment: I believe that the question is vastly improved and that @RISwampYankee's answer is on point.  I've moved my concerns to [chat] (http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8631883#8631883) because I don't want to conduct a debate in comments.

Answer (score 7):

You are referring to the [1999 Seattle WTO Ministerial Conference Protests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1999_Seattle_WTO_protests).

It is historically notable for breaking ground in two respects:

1) The way it was organized by the [Direct Action Network](http://www.socsci.uci.edu/~polletta/Articles%20and%20Book%20Chapters_files/This_is_what_demo_looks_like.pdf) (pdf) - their organization techniques allowed very different political allies to effectively communicate and collaborate with each other. This was more in-person rather than on-line, but it innovated processes and strategies (such as total consensus) that are still being effectively used today.

2) The way it was reported by the [Independent Media Center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indymedia), aka Indymedia. Indymedia relied on firsthand accounts, photos and videos by the participants, and provided a way to publish them directly on the internet in near real-time. This method of reporting on protests and other fast-moving political events (such as the Arab Spring) is now widespread, and use vehicles such as Youtube and Twitter - and this all began in Seattle in 1999.